# Radiobutton array (HTML)

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

If i have two inputs of type text with the same name, like this:

```
<input type="text" name="task" id="task1" value="begin">
<input type="text" name="task" id="task2" value="end">
```

When i submit the form `task` is automatically sent as an array (`task[0]='begin'`, `task[1]='end'`).
This is very useful for many reasons, for instance i don't have to worry about serializing the result, I can use a sortable to re-sort and when I submit it's already in the right order.

But if i want to use radio buttons, i have to use several inputs with the same name already.

Is there a way I could keep this functionality with radio buttons?

---

For instance:

```
<input type="text" name="task" id="task1" value="begin">
<input type="radio" name="time" id="time11" value="early" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="time" id="time12" value="noon">
<input type="radio" name="time" id="time13" value="late">

<input type="text" name="task" id="task2" value="end">
<input type="radio" name="time" id="time21" value="early">
<input type="radio" name="time" id="time22" value="noon" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="time" id="time23" value="late">
```

I want that when submitted i get `time[0]='early'` and `time[1]='noon'`

Comment: Why do you need that? You know the values of your radio buttons. And if you sent all the values, how would you know which one is selected?

Comment: dont quite get your question, but added a sample.

Comment: what server language you are using?

Comment: it's asp.net mvc but i believe task[0]/task[1] works for js/dom as well

Comment: What you need is a `<select>`, not a list of radio buttons.

Comment: i know i could use a select...

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was closed. It seems to me that there is a valid question here: "HTML will send text inputs with the same name to an array serialization. Radio inputs require the same name to associate a group of radio buttons. Can radio button responses be serialized as an array similar to what happens with text inputs?" +1 to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="text"  name="task[0]" id="task1"  value="begin">
<input type="radio" name="time[0]" id="time11" value="early" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="time[0]" id="time12" value="noon">
<input type="radio" name="time[0]" id="time13" value="late">

<input type="text"  name="task[1]" id="task2"  value="end">
<input type="radio" name="time[1]" id="time21" value="early">
<input type="radio" name="time[1]" id="time22" value="noon" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" name="time[1]" id="time23" value="late">
```

Then you'd get: `task[0]=begin`, `time[0]=early`, `task[1]=end` and `time[1]=noon`.

Comment: If you don't want to use 'begin' and 'end', use any string you want. Just put the bracketed key in the name property.

Comment: That depends on PHP's form parsing algorithm. I don't think ASP.NET gives any special significance to `[` and `]` characters in form data names.

Comment: @Quentin, if ASP.NET doesn't handle this natively as an array, you'd still have a unique property, as a string, of `time[start]`. So the code would still function, even though it would not be accessible as a native array.

Comment: @kingjeffrey — True, but getting a native array automatically is the point of the question.

Comment: @Quentin, and OP already referenced he was getting a native array from the text boxes, so one must assume he is using a server side scripting language (like PHP) that handles that in the manner expected by this answer.

Comment: @kingjeffrey — That is because every form parser I've seen (except the one in PHP which depends on special naming conventions which are usually a pain, but are quite useful in this edge case) presents multiple pieces of data *with the same name* as an array. However, since the objective is to get an array out of a bunch of radio buttons groups, you can't do that since giving them the same name makes them all part of the same (single) group.

Comment: getting an array is part of the objective, i also want to address it the right way, for instance associate `task[0]` with `time[0]`

Comment: @Quentin, It should work regardless. If handled as an array, each radio will store its value to the specified key within the 'name' array. If handled as a string, they are the same strings for related radio boxes. Not sure what the problem is you see.

Comment: @ariel, then use `name="time[0]"` and `name="time[1]"`. Like I said in the comment above, you can set the key to any string you choose, including 0 or 1.

Comment: @ariel, for that matter, you could explicitly state `name="task[0]"` and `name="task[1]"` for the text inputs as well, so there is no chance they get out of sync.

Comment: @ariel, I'll update the answer to explicitly show how this can be accomplished.

Comment: i see your edit, but read the question "This is very useful for many reasons, for instance i don't have to worry about serializing the result, I can use a sortable to re-sort and when I submit it's already in the right order."

Comment: yeah i know, all i would need is a js to reupdate the indexes, buuut

Comment: @ariel, The only way to have a serialized array in radio boxes where multiple inputs share the same name is to explicitly force the serialization. It can not happen unless you state the key value. So perhaps the answer you are looking for is: you can't do it automatically. But I thought it was better to show you how you can do it manually.

Comment: @kingjeffrey — If you have `name="foo[0]"` and `name="foo[1]"` then PHP will give you an array of post results containing a nested array called `foo` but everything else will give you an array of post results containing `foo[0]` and `foo[1]`. You don't get a special `foo` array (which is what the question asks for).

Comment: @Quentin, in the question, he does not ask for a literal array, but for a serialization of an array. HTML (as handled by all browsers) will post a serialization of an array regardless of how that serialization is handled by the server side script. Your concern is non sequitur.